# (Basic) Looking for Javascript code for validating setText() function

Tags: javascript, string, html

I am learning JavaScript basic stuff from a book. Could anyone please help me out i am really confused what code should i use **so that the setText() function validates that the target HTML id exists**. I know it going to be something really simple but i am new to this. Here is my JS code:

```
function setText(elementId, message) {
'use strict';

if ( (typeof elementId == 'string')
&& (typeof message == 'string')||(typeof message == 'number')
&& (typeof elementId !== '')
&& (typeof message !== '') ) {

    var output = document.getElementById(elementId);


    if (output.textContent !== undefined) {
        output.textContent = message;
    } else {
        output.innerText = message;
    }

} 
} 


function init() {
'use strict';
var today = new Date();
var message = 'Right now it is ' + today.toLocaleDateString();
message += ' at ' + today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes();


setText('output', message);

} 
window.onload = init;
```

Thanks

Comment: just avoid checking if textContent is part of the browser. all secure / major browsers have this.

Comment: Are you just looking to check if `output` is `undefined`?

Comment: btw.. check this out: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/#if-statement

Comment: Thanks Gottz it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...so that the setText() function validates that the target HTML id exists...

If it doesn't, you'll receive `null` from `getElementById`. So you can use that in an `if` (since `null` is "falsy"*), see the `***` line:

```
var output = document.getElementById(elementId);

if (output) {                                   // ***
    if (output.textContent !== undefined) {
        output.textContent = message;
    } else {
        output.innerText = message;
    }
}
```

---

* "falsy": A "falsy" value is a value that coerces to `false` when you use it in a condition. A "truthy" value is one that coerces to `true`. The falsy values are `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`; all other values (including all non-`null` object references) are truthy.